# Presto or Trino Custom UDF getting "do not match expected java types error"

Tags: java, presto, trino, presto-jdbc

I've created a custom udf that is registered but when I try to run `select do_protect('abc@test.com','Test_EMAIL');` I am getting following error:

> io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Exact implementation of do_protect do not match expected java types

Here is my Trino udf. I want to pass two string (VARCHAR) parameters.

```
@ScalarFunction("do_protect")
@Description("Return encrypted string")
@SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR)
public String protectUDF(@SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR) Slice slice1, @SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR) Slice slice2) throws PrivaceraException {
        logger.info("protectUDF get called...");

        String valueForEncrypt = slice1.toString();
        logger.info("AS :: valueForEncrypt :: "+valueForEncrypt);
        String schemeForEncrypt = slice2.toString();
        logger.info("AS :: schemeForEncrypt :: "+schemeForEncrypt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is incorrect. The mapping for VARCHAR *is* Slice. The issue you have is that you used String as the return value type. You should change that to Slice.

Comment: Based on https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/operator/scalar/StringFunctions.java , it seems you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the mapping of `VARCHAR` to `Slice`. Instead, I believe it should map to a `string`, as such:

`protectUDF(@SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR) string slice1, @SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR) string slice2)`

I found a similar issue on Stack Overflow:

[Presto Custom UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191433/presto-custom-udf)

Which led me to an article that shows the mapping for `VARCHAR` is `String`

*"CHAR, VARCHAR, and LONGVARCHAR could have been mapped to either String or char[], but String is more appropriate for normal use."*

[https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html)